# Can't get glVertexAttribPointer to render colour from shaders

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, pyopengl

I am trying to render 3 points with different colours, using a single VBO and shaders. I am passing the location and colour values to a single VBO:

```py
vertices = np.array([[0, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 1, 0], [0.3, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0.8, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype='f')
```

which I'm then trying to read into my shaders. I add alpha in the fragment shader. I'm using `glVertexAttribPointer` to differentiate between my x,y,z and my r,g,b,a. I am able to render my x,y,z:

```py
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position"))
glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position"), 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, None)
```

I am unable to load my r,g,b,a by using `glVertexAttribPointer` as I understand it from the docs:

```py
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"))
glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, 3*4)
```

This does not render any visible points. My shaders are definitely working, as when I change the byte offset of my Pointer to None:

```py
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"))    glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, None)
```

my points are coloured according to my normalized x,y,z coordinates (i.e `glVertexAttribPointer` interprets my x coordinate as r, y coordinate as g, z coordinate as b), which makes sense as the byte offset is 0. Surely the byte offset should be 3*4? My two thoughts were that I've either

1. misunderstood the final argument of `glVertexAttribPointer` or
2. somehow made the vertices transparent

but I've tried changing the ordering of my colours, adding alpha to the original dataset etc with no success. Any help appreciated.

Full code:

```py
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import pygame
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

def getFileContent(file):
    content = open(file, 'r').read()
    return content

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

    vertices = np.array([[0, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 1, 0], [0.3, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0.8, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype='f')
    vertexPositions = vbo.VBO(vertices)
    indices = np.array([[0,1,2]], dtype=np.int32)
    indexPositions = vbo.VBO(indices, target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)

    shader_program = glCreateProgram()
    vertex_source = compileShader(getFileContent("testing_vert_shader.vert"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragment_source = compileShader(getFileContent("testing_frag_shader.frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_source)
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_source)
    glBindAttribLocation(shader_program, 0, "position")
    glBindAttribLocation(shader_program, 1, "color")
    glLinkProgram(shader_program)

    print(glGetProgramiv(shader_program, GL_LINK_STATUS))  # shader linked == 1

    while True:
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glUseProgram(shader_program)

        indexPositions.bind()
        vertexPositions.bind()

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position"))
        glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position"), 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, None)

        # red vertices rendered if these two lines are commented out
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"))
        glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, None)  # changing last argument of glVertexAttribPointer to None results in x,y,z being read as colours

        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

        # Show the screen
        pygame.display.flip()

run()
```

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    vColor = vec3(color);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
in vec3 vColor;

out vec4 outcolor;

void main()
{
    outcolor = vec4(vColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a named buffer object is bound, then the 5th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glVertexAttribPointer.html) is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. However, the type of the parameter is still a pointer (`c_void_p`).

Hence the offset must be cast with [`c_void_p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). If the offset is 0, the 5th parameter can either be `None` or `c_void_p(0)`:

```py
loc_col = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color")
glVertexAttribPointer(loc_col, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 6*4, ctypes.c_void_p(3*4))
```